# Mysql join query not excluding rows with same id if one row fails the join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Table A has values

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Table B has values

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id |  status  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |  started |
|  2 |         2 |  stopped |
|  3 |         1 |  stopped |
|  4 |         1 |  stopped |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

A relation B is 1:N

How can I get only those ids from table A whose status is not Started.

```sql
SELECT 
   id 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.id=B.parent_id and B.status <> 'started';
```

When I run the above query I get this result

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

Instead of displaying only value 2, it is displaying 1 as well. What is wrong with the query I wrote?

Comment: I double checked it and the result seems fine. ID=1 from `A` has `parent_id = 1 && stopped` on `B` - these are the last two rows

Comment: Did you even read what result I am looking for?

Comment: Yes, you want the value only of `2`, but it's not the only `parent_id` with value `<> started`, so why do you expect only `2` then?

Comment: I wanted to check what is currently idle. Table A id 2 is idle where as Table A id 1 is not.

Comment: So you want there to be no records associated with `started`? If there's one - that it's not idle? You can use a subquery with `EXISTS` (or `NOT EXISTS`) or check the count(statuses) where they  are `started` to be zero

Comment: You are saying you want something in the question but you are saying you really want something else in the comments & you have not given an example & you haven't given the rest of a [mre]. And what you want is an easily found faq.--Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Display whose status is not started.

```
SELECT A.id FROM A JOIN B ON A.id=B.parent_id and B.status != 'started'
```

Output :

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  1 |
|  1 |
+----+
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I don't want 1 to show up in my final result because there is one row that fails this condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your query The parent_id 2 is return because is also stopped 
You coul try using a not in with subquery for stated

```
SELECT   id 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.id=B.parent_id 
WHERE B.parent_id NOT IN  ( 
    select parent_id
    from B
    B.status = 'started'
)
```

Comment: I want to avoid this query because this is an expensive query.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select a.id
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.parent_id = a.id and b.status = 'started')
```

This filters out rows from `a` for which *any* child record in `b` has status started.

Answer (score 0):

The 'not started' part of your query filters table B down to the following:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id |  status  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  2 |         2 |  stopped |
|  3 |         1 |  stopped |
|  4 |         1 |  stopped |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Your join is then looking for rows where id from Table A matches table B's parent ID - which it is returning correctly (but not counting 1 twice)

If you want the first half to return:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id |  status  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  2 |         2 |  stopped |
+----+-----------+----------+

 PLUS the rows from table A not referred to in table B....
```

Then GMB's answer above is correct -

```
select a.id
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.parent_id = a.id and b.status = 'started')
```

Here's a fiddle.
https://sqltest.net/#1005425

However, as proposed you're likely to end up with a lot of unnecessary duplication in table B - with many rows saying started and stopped, not necessarily chronologically (for example - the first record for A.id=1 suggested it was started, the 3rd and 4th records (presumably entered afterwards) stopped it, but you would be excluding this record for being started.

Why not change your table structure to update a single row?